# Can I connect to a jsadebugd process on a remote machine from Eclipse/IDE debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a java process running on a Linux box, but it cannot be started/re-started in debug mode. I read about the [jsadebugd](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jsadebugd.html) command and started the daemon, but I want to connect to it from an IDE(possibly Eclipse) debugger or maybe YourKit or jconsole. How can I do this? The remote JVM is 1.6+.

Comment: Where you able to find solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume since you mentioned Yourkit and other tool that what you really want to do is look at object state inside your applications. There are a couple of options, though I don't think it gets you the ability to set break-points like Eclipse or another debugger would (though I'd be intersted in hearing what restricts you from starting the process in debug mode - technical? process?)

1. have you tried connecting with: [VisualVM](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/jmx_connections.html)? I don't believe you need to start in debug mode, and it *will* give you the ability to navigate the object graph, and inspect objects. You can even use it to take heapdumps and do some ad-hoc analysis through them using [OQL](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/3115) queries.
2. If you're running on JDK6+ - have you tried instrumenting with btrace? Some [notes from the sailfin team](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/binod/archive/2008/06/sailfin_work_an.html) sounded promising, and like DTrace in Solaris, this seem like it would be useful in a variety of situations.

Comment: The process was already running and I wanted to see if I could peek into the JVM somehow. It had not been started in debug mode, so I was exploring options for this. In general though, Eclipse debugger and Yourkit are powerful enough to resolve issues as long as you have the processes setup accordingly. I have not tried btrace before, but I'll check it out.

Comment: @thimmayya Did those notes answer your question, or are you still looking?

Comment: the notes were helpful. I havent tried btrace yet, but the documentation does say that a BTrace program can be run against a running Java process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your restrictions correctly but you can start JVM with debugging server (serving JDWP) enabled. See for example "Sun VM Invocation Options" in http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html

Then you can connect your Eclipse debugger to running JVM. See "Remote debugging" section here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is exposed by Eclipse, but here's how to do it with jdb:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-VM/html/tooldescr.html#gbmog